# Object of type User is not JSON serializable error when logging using custom serializer

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use signals to check whether or not a user is logged in. Since I am using DRF when a user logs in they get a JWT token, I need to re-write `validate` to trigger user-logged-in when a user receives a valid token when logging in. However I am getting the error message:

```
Object of type User is not JSON serializable
```

Here is a breakdown of what I have tried:

this is my login API endpoint:

```
path('api/token/', CustomTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
```

My CustomObtainPairView:

```
class CustomTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

My CustomTokenPair Serializer:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer;
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView;
...
class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        credentials = {
            self.username_field: attrs.get(self.username_field),
            'password': attrs.get('password')
        }
        if all(credentials.values()):
            user = authenticate(request=self.context['request'], **credentials)
            if user:
                if not user.is_active:
                    msg = 'User account is disabled.'
                    raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)

                user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=self.context['request'], user=user)

                return {
                        # 'token': jwt_encode_handler(payload),
                        'user': user
                    }
            else:
                msg = 'Unable to log in with provided credentials.'
                raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)
        else:
            msg = 'Must include "{username_field}" and "password".'
            msg = msg.format(username_field=self.username_field)
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)

    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)
        token['username'] = user.username
        token['first_name'] = user.first_name
        token['last_name'] = user.last_name
        token['country'] = user.profile.country
        token['city'] = user.profile.city
        token['bio'] = user.profile.bio
        token['photo'] = json.dumps(str(user.profile.profile_pic))
        return token
```

and my models:

```
class UserLoginActivity(models.Model):
    SUCCESS = 'S'
    FAILED = 'F'
    LOGIN_STATUS = ((SUCCESS, 'Success'),
                    (FAILED, 'Failed'))
    login_IP = models.GenericIPAddressField(null=True, blank=True)
    login_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    login_username = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1,
                              default=SUCCESS,
                              choices=LOGIN_STATUS,
                              null=True,
                              blank=True)
    user_agent_info = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'user_login_activity'
        verbose_name_plural = 'user_login_activities'
```

I have been following this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@atulmishra_69567/tracking-user-login-activity-in-django-rest-framework-jwt-authentication-32e0194e77d0

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As per the implementation of `TokenObtainPairSerializer` and `TokenObtainPairView`, you have to return a JSON serializable output from the `validate(...)` method.

IMO, the easy method is to use a UserSerializer to serialize the `user` instance.

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"


class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        ...
        user = obtain_user_somehow_after_auth()
        
        """
        alternatively, you can use this too
        return {"user":{"id":user.pk, "email":user.email}}
        """
        return {"user": UserSerializer(user).data}
```

Comment: I still get `Invalid format string` when I try this